# Learning Bootstrap Thumbnails...why is that bullet showing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working through a book on Bootstrap and so far I am very impressed. Following the example given, I am supposed to see 2 rows of 4 thumbnails with a caption below them. I am getting a bullet to the left of the caption no matter what I do. Can someone guide me on how to get rid of that using just bootstap CSS?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Portfolio | My Bootstrap site</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Bootstrap Site</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="page-header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x40" />
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
            </li><!-- col-md-3 -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
            </li><!-- col-md-3 -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
            </li><!-- col-md-3 -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
            </li><!-- col-md-3 -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
            </li><!-- col-md-3 -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
            </li><!-- col-md-3 -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
            </li><!-- col-md-3 -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
                </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
            </li><!-- col-md-3 -->

        </ul>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src=".js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I get and the bullet should not be there according to the text of the book:

[image]

Comment: try adding `.thumbnails li{list-style:none!important;}` into your css file

Comment: That works, but I thought that with Bootstrap I shouldn't need to add that type of thing? Any idea why it isn't handled correctly out of the box?

Comment: Pardon me, I didn't understood your last point, will elaborate it please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at the [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), you will see, that it is geared towards `div` elements. When you replace the `ul` with `div class="row"` and the `li` elements with `div`, you will get the expected result

```
<div class="row thumbnails">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail" alt="" /></a><h4 class="thumbnail caption">Item Label</h4>
        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- col-md-3 -->
    ...
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c6e9/2/)
and [Full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/8c6e9/2/show/)

Comment: Thanks Olaf! The book I'm reading is using Bootstrap 2.x.x so I am having to convert the approach. It is very helpful to know this detail you provided.

Comment: With [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem), you use `span*` instead of `col-md-*`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nizam's code, the problem is solved. I still don't understand why it wouldn't work out of the box, but I have a solution now so I am not going to worry about it. The answer:

Add

```
.thumbnails li{list-style:none !important;}
```

to a custom css file. That did the trick for me.

Comment: I am glad that worked for you, even I wonder why it wasn't handled by BootStrap. Anyways just an improvement suggestion `.thubmnails li a{ text-align:center;}` it will bring li content to center, which will look better.